# Create and set the value of a twig variable, using index.loop in the variable name

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig

I need to define a twig variable name that can include an index.loop value within the variable name, so that I can later call this in another loop.

What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
{% for x in x.y.z %}
{% set myVar~index.loop = aValue %}
{% endfor %}
```

Later, I would be able to call:

```
{% if myVar2 == aValue %}
{{ display some stuff }}
{% endif %}
```

My problem is that I can't work out the correct syntax to define the variable (myVar~index.loop).

Any suggestions, greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: concatenate can be used with two strings or a sting with variable but not with two variables

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues you need to address here:

1. You would need to extend `twig` in order to create dynamic variables
2. The special variable `_context` is not sent (directly) towards a loop, but is being stored in `_context['_parent']`

---

*extending twig*

```
class MyTwigExtension implements \Twig\Extension\ExtensionInterface {
    /**
     * Returns the token parser instances to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return \Twig\TokenParser\TokenParserInterface[]
     */
    public function getTokenParsers() {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the node visitor instances to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return \Twig\NodeVisitor\NodeVisitorInterface[]
     */
    public function getNodeVisitors() {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of filters to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return \Twig\TwigFilter[]
     */
    public function getFilters() {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of tests to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return \Twig\TwigTest[]
     */
    public function getTests() {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of functions to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return \Twig\TwigFunction[]
     */
    public function getFunctions() {
        return [
            new \Twig\TwigFunction('set', [ $this, 'setValue'], [ 'needs_context' => true,]),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of operators to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return array<array> First array of unary operators, second array of binary operators
     */
    public function getOperators() {
        return [];
    }

    /**
    * Set reference to $context so you can modify existing values
    * Test if key _parent is set. If true this means the function was called inside a loop
    **/
    public function setValue(&$context, $key, $value) {
        if (isset($context['_parent'])) $context['_parent'][$key] = $value;
        $context[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

*add extension to twig*

```
$twig->addExtension(new \MyTwigExtension());
```

---

Now you can use the function `set` inside a template, e.g.

```
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
{% do set('my_var_'~foo, 'foo') %}
{{ my_var_bar }} {# output: foo #}
```

or inside a loop

```
{% for i in 1..10 %}
    {% do set ('my_var_'~i, i) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ my_var_6 }} {# output: 6 #}
```

---

As I said, the special variable [`_context`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#global-variables), is not send directly to the function, even with `needs_context` set true. `Twig` copies the current contents of `_context` inside `_parent` so that the loop get it's own private scope of variables and you can't overwrite any original value from the `_context`